# syntax error with rollup clause

Tags: mysql, sql, content-query-rollup

below is the query I am writing, but for some reason it gives me a syntax error right after the word 'ROLLUP' the little red squiggle line is under the ' ( ' after rollup.

```
SELECT building, room_number, time_slot_id, COUNT(*)
FROM class1
GROUP BY ROLLUP (building, room_number, time_slot_id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `With Rollup` in `group by`. Try this syntax

```
SELECT building, room_number, time_slot_id, COUNT(*)
FROM class1
GROUP BY building, room_number, time_slot_id WITH ROLLUP
```

for more info [**check here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: that gave me a result! thanks. im learning sql and the book for the class i take BLOWS!

Comment: @beau8008 -You are welcome. Your syntax is valid in `MSSQL` but not in `MYSQL`.

Comment: yeah, the book im using doesn't tell me what sql to use, and nor did my instructor. oh well, thanks again!